# Removing Prefixes in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have some code that adds a prefix to text in a label using the code

```
LblUsername.Text = "Welcome " & TxtUsername.Text
```

this code works perfectly but when I link this to other form using

```
 TDC.LblName.Text = Me.LblUsername.Text
    FTDC.LblName.Text = Me.LblUsername.Text
    MP.LblName.Text = Me.LblUsername.Text
    ALC.LblName.Text = Me.LblUsername.Text
```

i want to strip the prefix. Does anyone know how this is done??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you cold two thinks:
 1. Simple:

```
 TDC.LblName.Text = Me.LblUsername.Text.Replace("Welcome ","")
```

This simply removes the Welcome again.
 2. Better because more clean:
 Introduce a UserNameText Property and acess this property instead of the label. The main advantage is, that can be easily extended and is not as surprising as stripping the Welcome again afterwards.

Like this (in C#):

```
Public string UserName
{
get
  {
     return TxtUsername.Text;
  }
}
```

Then acess it liks this:
LblUsername.Text = "Welcome " & UserName
TDC.LblName.Text = Me.UserName

Comment: Thanks heaps Christian Suaer you are as legend